# How to update multiple dictionary keys that reference to the same value simultaneously?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a GUI program using PyQt6 and I am using QStyleSheet to stylize it, the stylesheet is hundreds of lines long and contains a lot of redundancies, so I want to write a class to manage the styling.

The basic idea is simple, I have a few template strings in a dictionary, and an instance of the class holds values of the attributes. A stylesheet is created by retrieving the right template strings and filling the attributes contained withing the instance's dictionary using string formatting.

The problem is that I want to change the styling, and I want the changes made be reflected on all widgets that use the same value. For example I have loads of widgets using the same text color, and I want to change the text color in one place and all other places that use the same value automatically get updated.

Example:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self._color = '#4000ff'
    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

dum = Dummy()
config = {'QLabel': {'color': dum.color}, 'QCheckBox': {'color': dum.color}}
dum._color = '#ff00ff'
```

The above code doesn't work:

```
In [115]: dum._color = '#ff00ff'

In [116]: config
Out[116]: {'QLabel': {'color': '#4000ff'}, 'QCheckBox': {'color': '#4000ff'}}
```

The intended result is:

```
{'QLabel': {'color': '#ff00ff'}, 'QCheckBox': {'color': '#ff00ff'}}
```

Of course I can change them one by one but that would be cumbersome. What are ways that I can mutate the string in one place and have all values referencing it get automatically updated?

---

What I want is basically a pointer, really. Something like the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using std::unordered_map;
using std::string;

string color = "#4000ff";


unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, string>> config = {
    {"QLabel", {
        {"Color", color}
    }},
    {"QCheckBox", {
        {"Color", color}
    }}
}

string *colorp = &color;
*colorp = "#ff00ff"
```

I know in C++ strings are mutable but that is beside the point. And of course the above code won't compile because it lacks a main function however it serves to illustrate the point.

And the existing answer doesn't solve the problem, because I have many attributes in a dictionary that is passed to the class constructor. I would need to use a function to dynamically add properties to the instance which would add much more complexity than needed.

---

And the method used in the answer won't work, either.

Here is a more comprehensive example:

```
style = """
QComboBox {{
    border: 2px {borderstyle} {bordercolor};
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: {background};
    color: {color};
    selection-background-color: {alternate_background};
    selection-color: {highlight};
}}
"""

values = {
    'borderstyle': 'outset',
    'bordercolor': '#552b80',
    'background': '#422e80',
    'color': '#c000ff',
    'alternate_background': '#7800d7',
    'highlight': '#ffb2ff'
}

style.format_map(values)
```

I need to do this for many widgets, the values are passed by a dictionary and I can't just store the object in the dictionary and query its attributes.

Comment: There's no link between the variable and the dictionary. When you create `config`, it copies the value of the variable into the dictionary. Updating the variable won't change the dictionary automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the attribute something that can be modified (not replaced) like a list.

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self._color = ['#4000ff']
    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

dum = Dummy()
config = {'QLabel': {'color': dum.color}, 'QCheckBox': {'color': dum.color}}
dum._color[0] = '#ff00ff'
```

Think of a list as a pointer to the objects it contains.

Answer (score 1):

This is Python's default behavior for object attributes, which is pass-by-value for immutable types like strings, numbers, and tuples. When you change the _color attribute of the `Dummy` class, it does not automatically propagate this change to the config dictionary.

One way to get around this is to store the `Dummy` object itself in the config dictionary, and access its color property whenever needed. This way, any changes made to the Dummy object will be reflected in the config dictionary.

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        self._color = '#4000ff'
    
    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, new_color):
        self._color = new_color

dum = Dummy()

# Store Dummy object itself
config = {'QLabel': {'color': dum}, 'QCheckBox': {'color': dum}}

# Update color
dum.color = '#ff00ff'

# Access color, it should be updated
print(config['QLabel']['color'].color)  # Output should be '#ff00ff'
print(config['QCheckBox']['color'].color)  # Output should be '#ff00ff'
```

[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference/29293411#29293411)

[Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)